# Using lambda to call a function with an argument but passing index rather than item

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, lambda, dearpygui

When trying to pass the current letter in the list of lowercase letters, it passes:

Current index + 24 * amount of times 'Click Me!' has been clicked

rather than just the item. Here is the code. Sorry for not being able to make it without dearpygui, I don't know how to recreate it without.

```
# pip install dearpygui
import dearpygui.dearpygui as dpg
import string

dpg.create_context()


def my_func_2(x):
    print(x)


def my_func():
    x = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
    with dpg.window(label="Test window 2"):
        for i in x:
            dpg.add_button(label=i, callback=lambda i=i: my_func_2(i))


with dpg.window(label="Test window"):
    dpg.add_button(label='Click Me!', callback=my_func)

dpg.create_viewport(title='Test')
dpg.setup_dearpygui()
dpg.show_viewport()
dpg.start_dearpygui()
dpg.destroy_context()
```

Answer (score 0):

Dear PyGUI callbacks can receive up to 3 parameters. From the [docs](https://dearpygui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/item-usage.html):

```
Callbacks may have up to 3 arguments in the following order.

sender:
the id of the UI item that submitted the callback

app_data:
occasionally UI items will send their own data (ex. file dialog)

user_data:
any python object you want to send to the function
```

You need to use the `user_data`, which can be configured on item declaration.

```py
def my_func():
    x = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
    with dpg.window(label="Test window 2"):
        for i in x:
            dpg.add_button(label=i, callback=lambda s, a, u: my_func_2(u), user_data=i)
```